# El selector nav no muestra el color del background

Tags: html, css

El selector `nav` no muestra el color del background que quiero.

Estuve inspeccionando y dice que tiene `0px` de *height*, y no entiendo por qué.

[image: Captura de pagina]

```css
/* Aqui comienza el codigo CSS*/

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#contenedor_principal {
  width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 131, 174);
  color: white;
  line-height: 90px;
}


/*! REVISAR ALGO LE PASA */

nav {
  background-color: #00ECFF;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.clearfix {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: #444;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#menu ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Ejercicio de CSS</title>
</head>

<!-- Body -->

<body>
  <div id="contenedor_principal">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
      <h1>Ejercicio de CSS</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- Menu de navegacion -->
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Articulos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categorias</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Contenido principal -->
    <main id="Principal">
      <section>
        <div class="clearfix">

        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Noticias de ultima hora</h2>
          <p>Texto de prueba</p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <aside>
      </aside>
    </main>

    <!-- Pie de pagina -->
    <footer>
      <p>Todos los derechos reservados &copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el *float* que estas utilizando en la lista, ya que esta propiedad remueve el elemento del flujo normal como se menciona a continuación en [propiedad float](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/float), o en otras palabras "se queda flotando".

Lo que yo sugeriria es que cambies la propiedad *display* a `inline-block` para que estos se alineen de forma horizontal y remueve la propiedad `float: left`, de tu lista para que deje de hacer lo antes mencionado.

Quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```css
/* Aqui comienza el codigo CSS*/

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#contenedor_principal {
  width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 131, 174);
  color: white;
  line-height: 90px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #00ECFF;
}

#menu ul li {
  /* ------- Aquí hacemos la modificación ------ */
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.clearfix {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: #444;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#menu ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Ejercicio de CSS</title>
</head>

<!-- Body -->

<body>
  <div id="contenedor_principal">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
      <h1>Ejercicio de CSS</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- Menu de navegacion -->
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Articulos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categorias</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Contenido principal -->
    <main id="Principal">
      <section>
        <div class="clearfix">

        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Noticias de ultima hora</h2>
          <p>Texto de prueba</p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <aside>
      </aside>
    </main>

    <!-- Pie de pagina -->
    <footer>
      <p>Todos los derechos reservados &copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, entendi perfectamente. Tendre cuidado con la propiedad float a partir de ahora. Saludos :)